# How to check if Firebase Firestore transactions have updated to server?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Firebase can work offline and then update the server when online. How can I check Firestore offline transactions have updated to Firebase server?

I want to show a warning to the user before they logout, that the server is not updated and they will lose the data if they logout.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I check Firestore offline transactions have updated to Firebase server?

You cannot! From the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions):

> Transactions will fail when the client is offline.

Also from the official documentation regarding [Enable offline data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline):

> For Android and iOS, offline persistence is enabled by default.

This feature caches a copy of the Cloud Firestore data that your app is actively using, so your app can access the data when the device is offline. You can write, read, listen to, and query the cached data. When the device comes back online, Cloud Firestore synchronizes any local changes made by your app to the data stored remotely in Cloud Firestore. **So there will be no data loss**.

If you want to know the source from where you are getting data, you can use the [isFromCache()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/SnapshotMetadata.html#isFromCache()) method:

> **Returns:**
>   true if the snapshot was created from cached data rather than guaranteed up-to-date server data. If your listener has opted into metadata updates (via `MetadataChanges.INCLUDE`) you will receive another snapshot with `isFomCache()` equal to false once the client has received up-to-date data from the backend.

```
documentSnapshot.getMetadata().isFromCache();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **hasPendingWrites** to check if the document has pending writing to the server.

Use **isFromCache** to check if the document was retrieved from the cache or server.

```
db.collection("myobjs")
    .get(Source.CACHE) // Change to Server if you want to load from server
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {

                        if (document.getMetadata().isFromCache() == true) {
                            Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " isFromCache => " + document.getData());
                        }
                        if (document.getMetadata().hasPendingWrites() == true) {
                            Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " hasPendingWrites => " + document.getData());
                        }
                    }

                    Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " offline => " + document.getData());
                }
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents.", task.getException());
            }
        }
    });
    });
```